# Call Javascript function from apex method

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have some buttons on my visualforce page which **onclick**, run a javascript function.

Sometimes however, the javascript function will need to run without the user actually clicking on the button. I need to call the javascript function from an apex method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As written and without knowing more - you can't. Controllers cannot execute javascript on the vf page directly - however they can run the code in the controller that the javascript does (if thats what is happening)

Comment: do you mean when you click on button first apex method called and after that javascript?

Comment: I just need a way to to activate my javascript when one of my apex method variables becomes a certain number. ex) if (variable == 10) {activate javascript function} @Eric

Comment: @Ratan see my most recent comment.

Comment: How is your variable value being changed? You might be able to accomplish this with the `oncomplete` event of your apex tag, but knowing when the variable has become a value will require using a re-render to update the page's DOM, then a query selector to find the updated value. There is no direct way for Apex (server side) to invoke javascript (client side) and pass it a value.

Comment: @D.S. Well that might work! For simplicity's sake, imagine a second button on my page which (when pressed) increments exampleVariable by 1. When this button is pressed 10 times, exampleVariable will equal 10. When exampleVariable == 10, I would like to run the JS function. Could you tell me more about your solution using a query selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reRender scripts that should be run when conditions are met. I wrote up an arbitrary example where you have (approximately) a 50% chance of getting a popup dialog, and 50% chance of just plain text. Every five seconds, the server is called again, and you may get a dialog popup. This requires no user interaction.

```
public class showAlertRandom {
    public boolean showAlert { get; set; }
    public Decimal numberValue { get; set; }
    public showAlertRandom() {
        doRandomAlert();
    }
    public void doRandomAlert() {
        numberValue = Math.random();
        showAlert = numberValue < 0.5;
    }
}

<apex:page controller="showAlertRandom" showHeader="true">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!showAlert}" id="alert">
            <script>
            alert('Hello World');
            </script>
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!not showAlert}" id="noAlert">
            No alert this time, sorry. Random value was: {!numberValue}.
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:actionPoller interval="5" action="{!doRandomAlert}" reRender="form" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

How it works:

Though Apex Code can't call JavaScript directly, it *can* set a variable to render a script block that can run arbitrary code. On each render, when the variable is true, an alert is produced. I wouldn't try doing this inside a closure or the middle of a script block, as you'll probably get very unpredictable results. You could dispatch a custom event or call some global function, if you prefer. You can use this technique anywhere reRender is supported, such as on a commandLink, commandButton, and actionFunction.

Comment: Great answer @sfdcfox. I have used this in the past. I always feel guilty using this though as it seems like an odd design pattern to have a self-executing script block get called by the DOM when salesforce does a rerender rather than using a callback (or oncomplete) pattern, but I haven't come up with something better.

TL;DR: This seems a bit dirty but it is quick and gets the job done.

Comment: Interesting... I have never heard of actionPoller before. So this works because the javascript is contained within an apex block?

Comment: It's an interesting approach. It's too bad that the minimum interval allowed on the actionPoller is 5 seconds. Still, it may be my only option. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexBrigham I don't think you need the actionPoller; you need any action. This could be a commandButton, commandLink, etc.

Comment: @AlexBrigham You said, for example, you have a variable incremented by 1 on each button press, with each 10th call doing something. You can do that by reRendering the block with something like `rendered="{!someVarabiable/10==0}"`.