# How to open a primary tab when a case is inserted using apex class?

Tags: apex, service-cloud-console

I have an util class in which I am inserting a new case, once the case has been inserted I want to open the case as primary tab in console app. I have written below method, my development mode is also turned off, not sure what is the issue. Below instanceURL is a custom label, I tried printing it in as well and it gives correct url. If I copy paste the URL in browser the case tab works but from one method I am calling this method and it is not opening a primary tab.

```
public pagereference redirectPage(Id caseId){
//added by sneh -- to be deleted
        system.debug('PARENT CASE ID------'+caseId);
        PageReference caseDetailRedirectPage = null;
        //PageReference conDetailRedirectPage = null;
        String instanceURL = Label.InstanceURL;
        system.debug('instance URL----'+instanceURL);
        //list<case> con = [select contactid from case where id =: caseid];
        caseDetailRedirectPage = new PageReference(instanceURL'console#%2F'+caseid);
        caseDetailRedirectPage.setRedirect(true); 
        return caseDetailRedirectPage ;
}
```

I am calling above method as `redirectPage(caseid)`. please let me know what am I doing wrong? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: can you explain what exactly are you doing with this `caseDetailRedirectPage = new PageReference(instanceURL'console#%2F'+caseid);` i think the issue is with this line of code.

Comment: try to add this line of code `caseDetailRedirectPage = new PageReference(instanceURL+'console#%2F'+caseid);`

Comment: You can (re-)enable your **development mode** by going to Advanced User details and then check Development mode.

Comment: @Mahmood the issue here is with development mode, I checkd in the community and according to other developers, it should be turned off. If it is on, SF will consider it as an iFrame and that resctrict the primary tab creation.

Comment: @RCS thank you for your response, but as  I mentioned in the question, the URL is not opening. I did try your line of code as well but no luck. inn system.debug it will give me the merged URL and it works fine if I just copy and paste it in browser. here I am trying to open a primary tab for newly inserted case in console app. I have live agent setup, once the chat ends, I am creating these cases in backend and I want to open that case in primary tab.

Comment: You need to check [Salesforce console toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_intro.htm).

Comment: Thank you @Mahmood. I actually did check it out before asking the question. OpenPrimaryTab(), but it is more into javascript, the issue here is I do not have a VF page that I can include JS in. I am trying to open tab from apex class, any help for that would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need a VF page somewhere. Apex is server side code and it can't control your browser or run javascript. The best option would be to use the apex to rerender a script block that would do what you need, similar to discussed here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100157/call-javascript-function-from-apex-method